# How can I make the same Scale from many subplots?

Tags: python, data-visualization

I have a lot of subplots (they are representing signals that I got from txt data). The amplitude on the y axe is in the signals different. How can I make them all in the same scale to have a relative interpretation of all the signals.

[image]

Comment: See `sharey` switch in `subplots` method.

Comment: Hi @bibi93, and welcome to StackOverflow. I suppose that you are using the Python module `matplotlib`. Is that a correct guess?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the function `subplot` from `matplotlib.pyplot`, then the parameter `sharey` is your friend. (Just as jlandercy pointed out in a comment.) Try something along the lines of:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# some code ...

plt.subplot(
    nrows = 2,
    ncols = 4,
    sharey= "all",
)

# some code ...
```

As of writing this answer, no code snippet was provided in the question, hence my example is vague.
If you haven't read the documentation, then I recommend you to do so: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html